# Regression Line to Data Points/ How to create vertical lines?

Tags: r, plot, visualization, lines, points

How one can get the following visualization in R (see below):
let's consider a simple case of three points.

```
# Define two vectors
x <- c(12,21,54)
y <- c(2, 7, 11)

# OLS regression
ols <- lm(y ~ x)

# Visualisation
plot(x,y, xlim = c(0,60), ylim =c(0,15))    
abline(ols, col="red")
```

What I desire is, to draw the vertical distance lines from OLS line (red line) to points.
[image]

Comment: I think this is a useful question. Perhaps consider editing the title to something more easily searched like `Plot vertical lines between fitted/regression line to data points` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you construct a  matrix of points, you can use apply to plot the lines like this:

Create a matrix of coordinates:

```
cbind(x,x,y,predict(ols))
#   x  x  y          
#1 12 12  2  3.450920
#2 21 21  7  5.153374
#3 54 54 11 11.395706
```

This can be plotted as:

```
apply(cbind(x,x,y,predict(ols)),1,function(coords){lines(coords[1:2],coords[3:4])})
```

effectively a `for` loop running over the rows of the matrix and plotting one line for each row.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this really nicely with `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)     
x<-1:10
y<-3*x + 2 + rnorm(10)
m<-lm(y ~ x)
yhat<-m$fitted.values
diff<-y-yhat     
qplot(x=x, y=y)+geom_line(y=yhat)+
       geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x, y=y, yend=yhat, color="error"))+
       labs(title="regression errors", color="series")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a much simpler solution:

```
segments(x, y, x, predict(ols))
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! You can also add the parameter `col="red"` to make the lines red. `segments(x, y, x, predict(ols), col="red")`